# Rails 4 with Devise: update_attributes doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, sql-update

I have a problem updating current_user attributes.
Here is my controller:

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController    
def create
        # ---- many_things
        #current_user.user_info.money = 1000
        current_user.user_info.update_attributes!(money: 100)
        #current_user.user_info.money = 1000 --- why not 100?
        # ---- many_things
    end
end
```

And here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_info
  before_create :initialize_user

  def initialize_user
    self.create_user_info!(money:1000,level:1)
  end
end
```

UserInfo model is blank:

```
class UserInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

update_attributes doesn't throw any exception, it seems that it doesn't save the record.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your logs

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set money to $100 or $1,000? If looks like you are setting and resetting the money attribute at the same time.

When you call the code block in create if sets the value to $100. After that, in the model, you have an after callback :after_create that runs initialize_user, which sets the value of money to $1,000. Perhaps you want a before callback on create instead?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You misunderstand, my fault: the `create` method is in the "building" controller, not in the User one. Now I edit my code, it should be ok ;)